# Typescript is not allowing empty object initialization

Tags: node.js, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

here I have a variable named body which will receive some data later and for now it is assigned as null:

```
const body: {
    "name": string,
    "photo": {
        "fileName": string,
        "file": NodeJS.ReadableStream,
        "encoding": string,
        "mimetype": string,
        "sizeInBytes": number,
        "publicUrl": string
    },
    "token": string
} = null;
```

but later when I receive data and try to put data like this:

```
body[someVariable] = someVariable;
```

it transpiles with no error but when I run js file it gives me error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fieldName1' of undefined
```

I searched on internet and found that an object must be initialized as with `{}` empty object to add properties further in it, but if I do something like that e.g: `body = {}` typescript error ays values are missing, I am not in position to make those values optional

Comment: workaround `(body as object) = {};`

Comment: You could do `const body = {} as {"name": string, ...etc... }` instead.  Note that if you can't make the properties optional then you should ideally be initializing the object with them already set.   Why can't you make the properties optional?

Comment: because values are coming from a web service, and some of them I am puting manually if doesn't come from service

Comment: So then why not `const body: {...} = Object.assign(objWithDefaultValues, valueFromService);`

Comment: because data is coming in different structure and data is huge, I only need few of them so I pluck the data I need from the webservice response and put in my object like this: `body[serviceRes.fieldName] = serviceRes.value`

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to your question.

First of all, you can't assign properties of a null or undefined object. In other 
words, if your variable is initialized to `null`, you can't access one of its properties and assign a value to it. That's a JavaScript error.

Then comes the TypeScript error. It looks like you want to declare optional properties on your object. You can do it with the `?` operator:

```
const body: {
  name?: string,
  photo?: {
    fileName?: string,
    file?: NodeJS.ReadableStream,
    encoding?: string,
    mimetype?: string,
    sizeInBytes?: number,
    publicUrl?: string
  },
  token?: string
} = null;
```

or with the `Partial` generic type:

```
interface BodyType {
  name: string,
  photo: {
    fileName: string,
    file: NodeJS.ReadableStream,
    encoding: string,
    mimetype: string,
    sizeInBytes: number,
    publicUrl: string
  },
  token: string
}

const body: Partial<BodyType> = {};
```

For more information about the `Partial` generic, takle a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

This way, you'll be able to specify the type of your object, without having to fill in every declared property at initialization. Ideally you wouldn't use the `Partial` except in specific occasions, and instead declare what properties are optional and what other are mandatory on an interface.

In any case, it depends on what your types mean. Does it make sense to have the `BodyType` interface, with all mandatory props? Then go for the `Partial` approach. Do you know in advance which properties can be undefined and which one can't? Then use the `?` operator.